# reading file line by line

Tags: perl

I have two files which I want to read line by line (the first contains a word per line and the second a sentence per line).

The goal is to calculate the **number of the sentences** from `file 2` containing a word being in `file 1`.

Here is my code:

```
open( my $words, '<:utf8', 'test' ) or die "Unable to open for read: $!"; `#test file is the file that contain my words`
open( my $sentences, '<:utf8', 'sentences' ) or die "Unable to open for read: $!"; `#sentences fila that contain one sentence per line`
open my $fh_resultat, ">:utf8", 'result';
my $word;
#i want to calculate the number of sentences from my $sentences that containe word from my file $words
while( defined( $word = <$words> ) ) {
    chomp $word ;
    $word =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
    my $nb = 0;
    my $idf;
    my $ph;
    while (defined ( $ph = <$sentences> ) ){
        my @tab = split(/ /, $ph);
        chomp @tab ;
        foreach my $val(@tab) {
            if($word eq $val){
                $nb = $nb + 1;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
    print $fh_resultat "$word:$nb\n";
}
```

but the processing is only performed for the first word of the first file!

Comment: If you're asking a number of people to read and understand your code, then it's polite to make it as easy to read as possible. I've done some light reformating to add some indentation and make your use of whitespace more uniform. Please do that yourself in future.

Answer (score 2):

When you read a filehandle to the end of the file, the next read from that filehandle will return `undef`. And it will continue to return `undef` no matter how many times you call it.

You cannot iterate through the phrase file without using the [seek()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) function to reset the file pointer to the start of the file.

```
seek $CorpusPhrases, 0, 0;
```

Alternatively, you might consider reading one (or both) of your files into memory so you don't need to keep reading the files.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code; the processing will only be performed for the first
word of the file because you iterate over the whole "sentence" file in the
the first line read from "word" file.

Two solutions where mentioned already; using seek and loading into memory.

I'm an advocate of loading the files into memory and process accordingly.

```
#test file is the file that contain my words
open( my $words, '<:utf8', 'test' ) or die "Unable to open for read: $!";   

#sentences fila that contain one sentence per line
open( my $sentences, '<:utf8', 'sentences' ) or die "Unable to open for read: $!"; 
open my $fh_resultat, ">:utf8", 'result';
my $word;

#i want to calculate the number of sentences from my $sentences that containe word from my file $words

#load sentences into memory
my @process;
while ( $line = <$sentences> ) {
    push (@process, $line );
}
close(sentences);

while( defined( $word = <$words> ) ) {
    chomp $word ;
    $word =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
    my $nb = 0;
    my $idf;
    my $ph;

    for $ph (@process) {
        my @tab = split(/ /, $ph);
        chomp @tab ;
        foreach my $val(@tab) {
            if($word eq $val){
                $nb = $nb + 1;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
    print $fh_resultat "$word:$nb\n";
}
```

Comment: You have a rather long-winded way of writing `my @process = <$sentences>;` :-)