# Extract data from an XML file with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I have an XML file like this containing thousands of entries

```xml
<mediawiki>
  <page>
    <title>page1</title>
    <revision>
      <id>2621</id>
      <parentid>6</parentid>
      <timestamp>2005-10-09T01:00:18Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Chaos</username>
        <id>2</id>
      </contributor>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">text1</text>
    </revision>
  </page>
  <page>
    <title>page2</title>
    <ns>8</ns>
    <id>7</id>
    <revision>
      <id>2619</id>
      <parentid>2618</parentid>
      <timestamp>2005-10-09T00:56:39Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Chaos</username>
        <id>2</id>
      </contributor>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">text2</text>
    </revision>
  </page>
  <page>
    <title>page3</title>
    <ns>8</ns>
    <id>6</id>
    <revision>
      <id>2621</id>
      <parentid>6</parentid>
      <timestamp>2005-10-09T01:00:18Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Chaos</username>
        <id>2</id>
      </contributor>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">text3</text>
    </revision>
  </page>
</mediawiki>
```

through my script, Each page must be in a text file whose name is the contents of the tag `<title>` and contains the text of `<text xml:space="preserve"></text>`

My code

```perl
my $filename = "pages.xml";
my $parser   = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc   = $parser->parse_file( $filename );
my $file;

foreach my $page ( $xmldoc->findnodes( '/mediawiki/page' ) ) {

    foreach my $title ( $page->findnodes( '/mediawiki/page/title' ) ) {

        foreach my $rev ( $page->findnodes( '/mediawiki/page/revision' ) ) {

            foreach my $text ( $rev->findnodes( 'text/text()' ) ) {

                $file = $title->to_literal();
                my $newfile = "$file.txt";

                open( my $out, '>:utf8', $newfile )
                        or die "Unable to open '$newfile' for write: $!";
                my $texte = $text->data;
                print $out "$text\n";
                close $out;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that every constructed file contains the same text as the last tag  `<text xml:space="preserve"></text>`

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of your post and added some indentation to your code. You're very welcome, but please make the effort to do that yourself in the future. If you're asking a large number of people to read and understand your post, it's polite to make it as legible as possible.

Comment: @DaveCross: I'm sorry to undo all your good work. It seems that I get no notification that there has been a superseding update when using a tablet to amend posts.

Comment: @Borodin: No worries. I assumed it was an accident.

Comment: @rim: Please make sure to edit the *latest version* of your question. I'm not sure why you made the change, as all you seem to have done is to remove one page from the XML. I've reinstated the edits that Dave Cross and I made, and added your new XML after reformatting it.

Comment: @rim: You were asked in a comment on your previous question [*reading file line by line*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44001137/622310) to tidy your code. It was done for you then, too. Before that, in [*Remove the first line from my directory*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43128122/622310) your poor formatting has been left as it is. I am sure you don't need a nurse to help you with your editing, so please will you try to present your questions a little better?

Comment: @rim: I also note that you haven't accepted or even commented on any of the answers that you been offered, ever. I'm raising your account with the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is nesting all those `for` loops and not using relative XPath expressions

This should do what you want

```perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

STDOUT->autoflush;

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "pages.xml";
my $doc      = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );

for my $page ( $doc->findnodes('/mediawiki/page') ) {

    my ($title) = $page->findnodes('title');
    my $file = $title->textContent;

    my ($rev_text) = $page->findnodes('revision/text');
    my $text = $rev_text->textContent;

    open my $fh, '>:utf8', $file
        or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for output: $!};

    print $fh "$text\n";

    close $fh;

    say qq{File "$file" written with "$text"};
}
```

#### output

```
File "page1" written with "text1"
File "page2" written with "text2"
File "page3" written with "text3"
```